# "it is in run"? Ways to express a functioning policy

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, synonyms

What are the ways to express a policy is currently in place in a country? Could I say:

> UBI is currently *in run* in Alaska.

Answer (score 5):

*In effect*, *in force* (though that usually for a policy that forces people to do - or not do - some specified thing), in some cases *deployed*. There are a few options.

*In run* isn't one of them. It's not even grammatical, I'm afraid. *Running*, the progressive participle, would be understandable, and even natural for some sorts of policy. "Alaska currently *runs* a UBI scheme" would be perfectly suitable. But *in run* has the dual problems of being ungrammatical and not used (one does not necessarily guarantee the other).

Comment: Thx, I don't see how would it be ungrammatical, tho. What is the grammatical difference between the theoretical phrase *in run* and *in effect*? Phrases often don't "correspond" to the grammaticality of their compounds.

Comment: *Effect* is a noun, in that sense. In the sense you are trying to use it, *run* is not a noun. You can't be *in* a bare infinitive verb. Where *run* is a noun, it means a route for running along, or a period of time spent running - and it's countable, so even if you did talk about something being *in* a run in that sense, it would be in *a* run, or in *the* run - and it's a different sense of run in the first place.

Comment: I agree but hypercorrectly, it should also be *in the effect*, shouldn't it?

Comment: No. Whether that's because you consider *in effect* a set phrase, or because of a property of the word *effect*, the phrase *in the effect* would be incorrect in this case. It would be correct in other (rarer) cases, where it has a different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

*effective* would work; [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/effective) even cites it as being used for a policy:

> 1. Successful in producing a desired or intended result.
>
> 1.1 (of a law, rule, or policy) operative.
>
> *‘the regulation will be effective from January’*

A variation on this would be *in effect*, and *operative* or *in operation* would work as well.

Comment: Thx, I suppose "in run" isn't an option then, right?

Comment: I haven't heard that usage before, but I'm not a native speaker myself.

Comment: @Probably Note that it would be idiomatic to say that a newly enacted policy is  **now running** (or, better, **now up and running**) somewhere. It would apply only in the case of something new.

Comment: You need to be careful with "effective" here, because meanings 1 and 1.1 quoted above can be *opposite* in some situations. A law which *is operative* may not necessarily *produce the desired or intended results!* - e.g. "The regulation which will be effective from January will not be effective" :)